# Loop over a list items in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to check if a set of directory exists or not. I am using a batch script.

I use "for" loop to loop over the list of the directories and checks if this directory exist or not:

```
set list=%HOME%\bin ^
%HOME%\tmp

for %%A in (%list%) do (
    if not exist %%A (
       echo %%A
    )
)
```

The problem is that I get an error: 'C:\mn\home\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or a batch file.

How to make the for loop avoid executing the items of the list?

Thanks

Comment: For checking the existence of a directory you should use a trailing backslash, e.g. `If Not Exist "%%~A\"`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you describe; hard to do anyway as you don't tell us the exact values of all your variables (like `HOME`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the list items in one line,
if they might contain spaces enclose in double quotes: `set list="%HOME%\bin" "%HOME%\tmp"`
separate items by space, comma, semicolon, tab or equal sign.

```
@Echo off
Set "Home=C:\mn\home"
set list="%HOME%\bin\",^
 "%HOME%\tmp\"

for %%A in (%list%) do (
    if not exist "%%~A" (
       echo doesn't exist %%A
    )
)
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_5053242.cmd
doesn't exist "C:\mn\home\bin\"
doesn't exist "C:\mn\home\tmp\"
```

**It might be easier to put your items into the for directly:**

```
@Echo off
Set "Home=C:\mn\home"

for %%A in (
"%HOME%\bin\"
"%HOME%\tmp\"
"%HOME%\blahtmp\"
) do (
    if not exist "%%~A" (
       echo doesn't exist %%A
    )
)
```

Comment: It does run here, what is contained the variable `%home%`? In an open  cmd window issue a `set home`

Comment: Sorry, I just realized it did double double quoting, changed my answer. Please try again.

Comment: It still gives me the same error! the error is issued in from "set list" command even before executing the for loop.

Comment: You still didn't tell what the variable `Home` contains, I set a dummy content `C:\mn\home` in the above version and get that sample output.

Comment: variable "HOME" points to my working directory. I set it appropriately in the  script.

Comment: I'm not interrested in the exact content but need to know if it contains any double quotes. Here the code runs without flaw, so if neccessary anonimize it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Putting the list items in one line works fine. However, I am dealing with a long list of items, so I am trying to split the list items on many lines. 
Splitting the list on more than one line using ^ still produces the same error.

Comment: When using multiple lines, ensure that the continued lines begin with at least a _space_, because otherwise the `^` escapes the first character (`"` in your case)!

Comment: @aschipfl thanks for the hint. **AT**mnabil the appended variant (posted this 3hours ago, but got somehow lost)

Comment: Thanks a bunch; it works now using your edited answer.

Comment: Appreciate the (late ;-) feedback!